# How to get rollback to use the older image instead of staying on the newest (externally built)?

Tags: openshift, rollback, openshift-client-tools

We are moving our build process outside our OpenShift 3.11 cluster and have noticed that when wanting to rollback to an older deployment the docker image used is not the old one but the newest one known to OpenShift.

I saw for images built by an OpenShift source build that this worked, but for our externally built images which are pushed to the openshift external docker registry and then `oc new-app registry/foo/bar:master` (which creates an image stream for this) this does not work.

Can this be achieved at all?

Do I need extra metadata on my docker image?

Do I need to tell OpenShift more about my image?

---

Note:  Opened https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/23754 in Origin - the open source project below the Redhat stuff - about this

Comment: You should avoid using `master` as the image tag version, start using unique version numbers for each image build if you want to be able to roll back to old versions.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton i need to follow a tag. Do you say I need more than that tag?

Answer (score 3):

Use [immutable tags](https://vsupalov.com/docker-latest-tag/).

As you are addressing your images with a tag called `master`, I assume the you are currently using mutable tags that get updated with every image build. With this, you can just “roll back” by reverting your commit and re-building your old image, but then you still get an updated base image and different metadata.

If you design your whole release process around immutable tags you can do exactly what you want. To achieve that, use one of the following approaches:

(1) Address your image via [image digest](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-an-image-by-digest-immutable-identifier). In that case, you need a registry that keeps your images even if they are not tagged. For example, Quay.io does not keep untagged images and you can only pull the latest version. To avoid that, just add a dummy tag, e.g. the image digest.

(2) Release your images with semantic versioning, e.g. by using [Angular commit messages](https://gist.github.com/stephenparish/9941e89d80e2bc58a153) and adding [semantic-release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release) to your build pipeline. Make sure that the base image you are using is immutable, too. To deploy the images to the our cluster, use a [GitOps](https://www.weave.works/blog/kubernetes-anti-patterns-let-s-do-gitops-not-ciops) workflow with a tool like [Flux CD](https://fluxcd.io). Now you can easily roll back by reverting a commit in your GitOps repo.

(3) Reconsider whether you need rollback at all. Alternatively, you can use canary deployments with Istio that comes with OpenShift 4. Instead of rolling back, you just deploy two versions of your app at the same time, then you use Istio to route the traffic to the one or the other until you are happy.

Comment: We are using an OpenShift external docker registry.  We may also use a Habor instance instead.   OpenShift 4 is not an option.  If I understand you correctly, you essentially say that I need to manually (or using a non-OpenShift tool) keep track of the images to deploy and hence therefore manually deploy them so the deployment descriptor contains  the unique tag given by me that rollback needs to locate the old image?   Is there no way that OpenShift can do this given sufficient hints at one time?

Comment: The `sufficient hints` can only be the tags mentioned at [https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/core_concepts/builds_and_image_streams.html]. They include the image digest I mentioned in (1). Have these been created? And does `oc rollback` work?

Comment: The image digest tags have not been created explicitly.  Unfortunately I do not have time to investigate further before the bounty runs out, så I have awarded it to you on good faith, and I'll come back to it later.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For rolling back to a specific version you just need to specify the version, newest will be rolled back to automatically if you dont specify deployment version.

[DOCs](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/dev_guide/deployments.html#rolling-back-a-deployment)

> Image change triggers on the deployment configuration are disabled as
>   part of the rollback to prevent unwanted deployments soon after the
>   rollback is complete. To re-enable the image change triggers:

```
$ oc deploy <deployment_config> --enable-triggers
```

> To roll back to aspecific version:

`$ oc rollback <deployment_config> --to-version=1`

Comment: I am looking at the rollback button in the GUI which for images built by a Build Config can roll back to that specific image, but appears to for images imported from the external registry not to do that but use the newest docker image which for me is an error.  Are we talking about the same thing?

Comment: I think we are talking about same thing except that I invoke command directly from CLI, do you have any traces for what happens when you click GUI button?

Comment: From what I read you are talking about the deployment descriptor version, that works!  The problem is that the deployment back then referred to an older image in the image stream than the one being used when the old deploiyment descriptor is being rolled back to.  Like "deployment 2" but using "image 5" instead of "image 2".

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen ah ok so wrong image is pulled. something like this issue?
https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/13302

Comment: Doesn't look like it.  I will open an issue though, just to see if it _is_ a bug.

Comment: Well I am interested in this issue, so if you get time we can review together step by step how your process works.

Comment: I opened this issue:  https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/23754  No reaction so far.